# Remove the form input fields data after click on submit?

Tags: php, jquery, html

hi i am using a form for users subscription on the website with target is _new.
when i click on the submit button that the submitting message shows on the new window but the previous window still holding the data.
How to remove input fields data after submitting.

```
<form target="_new" action="samplepage.php"  method="post">
<input type="text" name="inputtxt1" />
<input type="text" name="inputtxt2"  />
<input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

Make the autocomplete - off

try this

```
<form target="_new" action="samplepage.php"  method="post" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="inputtxt1" />
<input type="text" name="inputtxt2"  />
<input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

Comment: yep i agree mr. @Big Chris.. but its the easy way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set value to `null` for `text field` using `jquery` on `submit` button click

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function()
    {
        $("input[type=text]").val('');
    });
```

**EDIT:**

I don't know is this a good approach,  use `blur` instead of `click` event

```
$("input[type=submit]").blur(function()
    {
        $("input[type=text]").val('');
    });
```

But it will meet your need.

Comment: we have to make the values empty after the form is submitted

Comment: k, i will try...can you use ajax??

Comment: thanx i have added the jquery time delay in your first answer then it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('form_name').submit(function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').val('');

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset form data using this

```
$('form').get(0).reset();
```